# Keyerror even though column exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Below is the code I used:

```
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(temp, columns=["Top","Column number","Row number"])
temp_df = temp_df.sort_values(by=["Top"],axis=1)
```

The second line is throwing the following error:
[image: error]

I literally have no clue as to why it is throwing an error.
Please help me out.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve the problem on your own? It'll be easier for people to help you if you can show what you have tried.

Comment: please don't paste images of code or data (image 2 is fine as an illustration, but 1 and 3 are not): that makes it so much more difficult for us to help.

Comment: no, I hadn't downvoted. But thx for updating. You can also paste the text of an exception rather than an image of it...

Comment: @PierreD I ran into a different error this time. Can you please look at the updated question and let me know a possible fix for that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: that sounds like a completely different question. Please revert to the original (otherwise nobody will understand what the accepted answer is about) and ask a new question. Same rules as usual: provide an MRE, don't paste images, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226639/discussion-between-ravi-and-pierre-d).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the `axis=1` in your `.sort_values()` that's causing problems: there is no such index `'Top'` (but there is a column `'Top'`).

In other words, change your second line to:

```
temp_df = temp_df.sort_values(by='Top')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, mate. I ran into a different error this time. Can you please look at the updated question and let me know a possible fix for that.